# how to get IE9 to display pdf files in the browser?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, adobe-reader

Pdf files were displaying in the browser, but then I accidently right clicked it and set it to not display pdf's in the browser. How can I set it so it does display it again?

I tried going into adobe reader preferences and internet, but the option is grayed out and checked, yet it still doesn't work in IE9...

I also tried reinstalling (repairing) adobe reader version 10.1.4

Thanks.

Comment: is there a reason your using ie? Thats the browser we're all trying to nuke.

Answer (score 5):

First (as said on [adobe's help](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/cant-view-pdf-web.html#main_9__View_the_PDF_in_a_32_bit_version_of_Internet_Explorer__not_a_64_bit_version)) make sure you are using IE9 32-bit version. And check if addon is enabled in IE9.
There are a lot of solutions on that help page, I think there is one that suits your situation.

I've had Reader 8, just removed and installed new version and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

#### In Adobe Reader:

1. Click on Edit
2. Click on Preferences
3. Click on Internet (about half way down on the left).
4. You should either have:

   - a) An option that says open adobe in browser
   - b) There should be the following link to show you how to ensure the addon is working properly.

     - http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-browser-acrobat-xi.html

#### In Internet Explorer 9: <sup>(according to the link above)</sup>

> 1. Open Internet Explorer, and choose Tools > Manage Add-ons.
> 2. Under Add-on Types, select Toolbars And Extensions.
> 3. In the Show menu, select All Add-ons.
>      [image: Select All Add-ons]
> 4. In the list of add-ons, select Adobe PDF Reader.
>      **Note**: *If you do not see the Adobe PDF Reader add-on, try the other options on the menu. For example, on some systems, the add-on appears when you select Run Without Permission.*
> 5. Click the Enable or Disable button (it toggles depending on the status of the selected add-on):
>      **Enable** sets the Adobe PDF Reader add-on to open PDFs in the browser.
>      **Disable** turns off the add-on so it does not open PDFs in the browser.
>      [image: Click the Enable/Disable button]

Answer (score 0):

Had this happen to me after I installed Adobe Acrobat Pro
The browser does not know what PDF viewer to use ( Acrobat or Reader)

Open Adobe and go to:

> Edit --> Preferences --> General --> Select Default PDF Handler --> 
>   A pop-up will appear. Select one from the dropdown.

Solved it for me.